# Print High Resolution Image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am printing image 2349 x 3600 pixels.  I have resized image but printing is blurred not clean.  Please looke at code -

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

public Bitmap resizeimage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(850, 1101);
    using (Graphics grap = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {            
        grap.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        grap.InterpolationMode  = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;
        grap.SmoothingMode      = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        grap.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
           
        grap.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 850, 1101);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I tried everything from changing bitmap size, quality of graphics but still image blurred.
I used microsoft office 2007  and resized image and printed it , it was so clear.
How I can get exact printing quality as I got  in microsoft office 2007.
Please help.

Here is code before drawing -

```
PrintPreviewDialog printpreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();

PrintDocument printdocument = new PrintDocument();

printdocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON L100 Series";
int horizantal_dpi = printdocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
int vertical_dpi   = printdocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y;

decimal final_width_dpi  = (((int)printdocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width  * horizantal_dpi) / 100);
decimal final_height_dpi = (((int)printdocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height * vertical_dpi  ) / 100);

printimagaprint = new Bitmap((int)final_width_dpi, (int)final_height_dpi);

//set resoultion
printimagaprint.SetResolution(horizantal_dpi, vertical_dpi);

Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(printimagaprint);
g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, printimagaprint.Width, printimagaprint.Height);

printdocument.PrintPage +=new PrintPageEventHandler(printdocument_PrintPage);

//printdocument.Print();
printdocument.DocumentName = textBox1.Text;
printpreview.Document = printdocument;
printpreview.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Your code makes little sense. What is the source bitmap, and why do I see 850x1101 as size for the draw image? How do you print it?

Comment: You code is incomplete as TomTom points out. There isn't much to go by, however you might want to set your image at 300dpi or ensure you match you printer's resolution before printing.

Comment: This is pretty fundamental, a printer has a resolution that's easily 6 times better than your monitor.  Monitors are usually 96 dpi, an inkjet or laser printer is 600 dpi.  So every single pixel in the bitmap is turned into a 6x6 blob of ink on paper.  Your arms are not long enough to hide that.  The only true countermeasure is to print the bitmap 6 times smaller so every pixel in the bitmap maps to one pixel on the printer.  Or to use a much bigger bitmap.

Comment: Hi @shree-software,  have you solved the problem?

Comment: `printimagaprint = new Bitmap((int)final_width_dpi, (int)final_height_dpi);` <-- This looks wrong. The `Bitmap(int,int)` constructor sets the image dimensions, not the DPI, which your code does on the line below with `SetResolution` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the printer resolution before printing.

```
printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = GetTargetPrinter(); 

int horizontal_dpi = printDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
int vertical_dpi = printDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y;
Decimal final_width_dpi = (((int)printDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width * horizontal_dpi) / 100); 
Decimal final_height_dpi = (((int)printDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height * vertical_dpi) / 100);

printImage = new Bitmap((int)final_width_dpi, (int)final_height_dpi);

// Set Resolution
printImage.SetResolution(horizontal_dpi, vertical_dpi);

Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(printImage);
```

And please try to provide more descriptive code. I am just making assumption for now.

Comment: Thanks , please look at my complete code , I am generating print preview and then printing this image.

Comment: I added your code above but still it is generating large image in print preview , please look.